# python django rest framework. How to serialize foreign key UUID in some specific format?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models A and B and both of them has UUID as primary keys. There is a foreign key in `B` related to `A`.

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)

class B(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    for_key = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

And here comes my serializer,

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'desc')

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('id', 'desc', 'for_key')
```

As you can see, I have change the uuid(primary key) to hex format. But the format of the `for_key` is in the default format (hex_verbose).
So how can I serialize the **foreign key** `for_key` in model B to **hex** format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to be able to specify the `for_key` then you can't use @Withnail's answer because the `for_key` there is read_only. 
You should use a [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield).

```
  class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    for_key = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=A.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('id', 'desc', 'for_key')
```

Answer (score 2):

When you serialize across a relationship in DRF, you just need to [call the serializer in the second model](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

```
class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ('id', 'desc')

class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    for_key = ASerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ('id', 'desc', 'for_key')
```

Comment: Sounds good but I post a data to B with `{"id": "XXX", "desc": "deschere", "for_key": a id in A}`. It returns no error but the `for_key` column show null...

Comment: It'll depend on what you're posting back, hex or hex_verbose, as a starting place - it's hard to say without seeing the code/example though.

Comment: I post a data to A with `hex` format and I can see it in the table; Then I post data to B with id and  `for_key` both in `hex` format. After that the `for_key` column I posted is in the default `hex_verbose` format....

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is :

```
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')
    for_key = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex', source='for_key.id')
    class Meta:
      model = B
      fields = ('id', 'desc', 'for_key')
```